# Python, Regexp: Place list of strings in regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, valueerror

I have a regex that identifies strings of a price format:

```
import re
price = re.compile(r'^.*[\$\£\€]\s?\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?.*$')
```

However, I would like to have a function that is able to place a list of currency symbols into the first character set above rather than just the three that I have identified. So for example,

```
import re
currencies = ['$', '£', '€']
key_characters = '|'.join(currencies)
price_re = re.compile(r'^.*[({})]\s?\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?.*$')
word = re.compile(price_re.format(key_characters))
```

When I try to run the final 'word' function, I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '1,3'
```

When I remove one of the two numbers listed above, the third line of the Traceback changes to:

```
ValueError: cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification
```

Is there a way to do what I would like? Is it a matter of having redundant '|' characters in the set?

Comment: You cannot `format`  a regex object. Do it with a string. Then, double the literal curly braces. Do not use a group inside `[...]`, just use `[{}]` and join with empty string.

Comment: Strange, when I run your code, I don't get KeyError, I get `AttributeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object has no attribute 'format'`. Are you sure this is the code you're running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot format a regex object, you should do that with a string. Then, you need to double the literal curly braces so that they could be parsed as literal `{` and `}`. Do not use a group inside `[...]`, just use `[{}]` in the format string and `join` the keys with an empty string rather than `|`.

You may use

```
import re
currencies = ['$', '£', '€']
key_characters = ''.join(currencies)
price_re = re.compile(r'[{}]\s?\d{{1,3}}(?:[.,]\d{{3}})*(?:[.,]\d{{1,2}})?'.format(key_characters))
for m in price_re.findall(r'$13344,34, £3424, €7777'):
    print(m)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qN3m2a).

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful.

Comment: @JackReimer If anything is unclear, please drop a comment,  I am in a rush, and could not explain all in minute details.